# Vim shows python errors on exit

Tags: python, vim, flake8

Every time I try to exit vim, it shows me all of the errors in python. I do not want this. This is a screenshot of what I am talking about. [image]

How can I fix this? TIA.

Comment: which plugins are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be output from `vim-flake8` plugin. You probably need to uninstall or disable the plugin, or remove autocommand that runs `flake8` on saving Python file.

I cannot give more detailed answer — I need to see your `.vimrc` and perhaps the content of `.vim` directory.

If you don't want to disable `vim-flake8` but only want to get rid of its output on exit — add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
" automatically close quickfix if it's the only window left"
autocmd WinEnter * if winnr('$') == 1 && &buftype == "quickfix" | quit | endif
```